# Массив типа char и указатель. C++

Tags: c++

const int arrayLength = 9;
    char name[arrayLength] = "Jonathan";
    int numVowels(0);
    for (char *ptr = name; ptr < name + arrayLength; ++ptr)
    {
        switch (*ptr)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
            case 'I':
            case 'i':
            case 'O':
            case 'o':
            case 'U':
            case 'u':
                ++numVowels;
        }
    }

```
std::cout << name << " has " << numVowels << " vowels.\n";
```

Есть такой фрагмент кода. Когда я создаю указатель на массив, то указатель получает адрес первого элемента массива. Но почему-то когда я пишу `std::cout << ptr` то я получаю `Jonathan`. А если пишу `std::cout << *ptr` , то получаю `J`. Как получается так, что я разыменовал `Jonathan` как `J`. Я понимаю, что если бы я создал `int array[]` и написал `std::cout << array` то получил бы какой - то адрес, а как получается, что при создании такого же массива толЬко типа char я получаю вместо адреса строчку, а если я напишу `std::cout << &name` то как раз таки получу адрес ( адрес первого элемента же? ).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88509/discussion-on-question-by-kaznachei---char---c).

Answer (score 3):

В этом коде не создается ни одного указателя на массив. `ptr` - Это указатель на первый элемент, да. Если написать `std::cout << ptr`, то вызовется перегрузка для типа `char const *` которая будет печатать не адрес указателя, а оканчивающуюся нулем С-строку. Чтобы напечатать адрес достаточно сделать приведение:

```
::std::cout << static_cast<void const *>(ptr);
```

Comment: А почему `void` перед `const *`?

Comment: @Kaznachei Чтобы тип получившегося указателя был отличен от `char const *`

Comment: Потому что ptr и так имеет тип `char *`? А как этот тип `const void *` работает?

Comment: @Kaznachei Честно говоря, непонятно, о что вы спрашиваете

Comment: Просто, не понимаю что это за тип такой `void *`.

Comment: @Kaznachei `void` - это специальный встроенный неполный тип, `void *` это просто указатель на что-то, указатели `void *` нельзя разыменовывать

Comment: Я знаю только то, что `static_cast<>` создает копию переменной определенного типа , образуя копию  другого типа. А как в данном случае static_cast<> работает. Мы же не тип указываем, а указатель

Comment: @Kaznachei Указатели - это тоже типы, ровно как и ссылки. В записи `void * p;` `void *` - это тип, а `p` - это имя переменной, по которому можно обратится к значению указателя.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, обьяснить, как ptr преобразуется так, что оператор << выводит адрес

Comment: @Kaznachei `ptr` в этой конструкции вообще не трогается, `static_cast` возвращает новый указатель со значением, скопированным из `ptr`. Главное в том, что теперь не будет вызываться перегрузка оператора `<<`, принимающая на вход `char const *`, а вызовется другая перегрузка, которая напечатает просто адрес.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А можно спросить насчет адреса. Если я определяю `char name[9] = "Jonathan"`, то `name` содержит адрес на что?

Comment: @Kaznachei `name` - это не адрес, это массив (который при необходимости может неявно приводиться к указателю на `char`). Давайте для новых вопрос вы будете создавать новую тему, ок?

Answer (score 2):

Разыменование вашего `ptr` - это именно `J`, а не никакой не `Jonathan`

А что будет получаться при

```
std::cout << ptr;
```

зависит от того, что написано в перегрузке оператора `<<` для типа вашего `ptr`. Там можно написать что угодно, в том числе всегда выводить слово `"Вася"`. Как вы сами понимаете, никакого отношения поведение этого оператора к собственным свойствам `ptr` не имеет и удивлять вас это поведение не должно.

Ваш `ptr` имеет тип `char *`. Специально для `const char *` в стандартной библиотеке написана перегрузка оператора `<<`, которая выводит содержимое всей С-строки, указываемой этим указателем. Его вы и наблюдаете.

Остальные указательные типы в вашем примере попадают в перегрузку оператора `<<` для типа `const void *`, которая просто выводит адрес.

Comment: То есть << перегружен для `char *` и если видит `char *` , то выдает не адрес, а что содержится в массиве ?

Comment: @Kaznachei: Именно так. Только не "в массиве", а "в С-строке".